# How do I combine the 'less' and 'head' comands?

Tags: command-line, pdf, less

I am attempting to preview a PDF in the terminal on Ubuntu 17.04.  I can view the PDF clearly using the 'less' command, but it shows the entire file.  If I use the 'head' command, I get the first 10 lines but the preview is gibberish.   I attempted to combine the commands using '&&' but all it did was apply both commands separately.

Is there any way for both to act at the same time?  In other words, I want to legibly preview the first 10 lines of the PDF.

Comment: Since `less` is a pager, why not just press `q` when you're done viewing however many lines you want to see?

Comment: I can do that, but I wanted to see if there was a way to combine them that doesn't have me enter a new "window."

Comment: The thing is, a PDF needs to be read completely for it to be displayable (important information is stored at the end of the file). So, you'd need to do something like: `less foo.pdf | head`, or figure out which program `less` is using to generate the preview and do: `<preview prog> foo.pdf | head`.

Comment: Do you use `less` for anything other than getting the preview? Is the paging functionality not needed?

Comment: AFAIK `less` uses the `lessfile` filter, which runs `pdftotext` under the hood; what happens if you run `pdftotext somefile.pdf - | head`?

Comment: steeldriver and muru 'less somefile.pdf - | head' worked.  Thank you!